# Solving Cauchy problem PDE and drawing the solution graph

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I want to solve and draw the solution of PDE such that

\begin{align}
\rho_t +2\rho\rho_x=0
\end{align}

and with initial condition

\begin{align}
\rho(x,0)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if  $x<0 $}\\   
2 & \text{if  $0\le x \le1$}\\   
1 &\text{if  $x >1$}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

This is a form of Cauchy problem, I reparametrized it as:

$\xi'(z,t)=2\rho(x,t) \implies \xi(z,t) =2\rho t+z$

Then I got

\begin{align}
\xi(z,t)=
\begin{cases}
2t+z &\text{if $z<0$}\\
4t+z &\text{if $0\le z\le 1$}\\
2t+z &\text{if $z>1$}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Until this, is it all correct?

Also, I tried to draw the solution, but how can I do it?

Comment: Note that you can write you equation as $$\rho_t+(\rho^2)_x=0$$ equivalently $$\partial_t \rho+\partial_x f(\rho)=0$$ with $f(\rho)=\rho^2$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the formation of shocks or viscose limit solutions?

Comment: Have you seen plots of characteristic curves in the $t$-$x$ plane for these types of equations before? Try drawing these curves for your equation that start in the different regions defined by the piecewise parts. It should be pretty simple until they start intersecting, then you will have to look into shock and rarefaction conditions.

Comment: @whpowell96 oh yeah that is my problem